# Initiate css animation once background image of div is loaded.

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I want to make sure that the background image of where the text animation will take place is loaded before it starts. It doesn't necessarily have to check if all background images or images on that page are loaded, only this specific one, so the animation doesn't take place on the body's background.

Image is loaded with a data attribute via a parallax script.

I have tried to add the image inside a load function, but it doesn't seem to load at all.

All of it is inside a document ready.

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://s27.postimg.org/ya4yhbmzn/image_Example1.jpg">

    <h1>First Title</h1>
    <h2>Second Title</h2>    

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 80px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h1, h2{
     opacity: 0; 
}
```

JAVASCRIPT not working:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#myDiv').attr('data-image-src', 'http://s27.postimg.org/ya4yhbmzn/image_Example1.jpg').load(function() {

    $('h1').css('opacity',1).addClass('slideInDown').css('opacity',1);

    setTimeout(function() {$('h2').addClass('slideInUp').css('opacity',1);}, 1000);

    });
});
```

JAVASCRIPT THAT WORKS (but sometimes images load delays and animation takes place):

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $('h1').css('opacity',1).addClass('slideInDown').css('opacity',1);

    setTimeout(function() {$('h2').addClass('slideInUp').css('opacity',1);}, 1000);

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqnLovcm/2/) to show the working example and the code I tried to use to check if a background image has been loaded.

Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: Waiting for images to load can be tricky. I have used this plugin which helped me out before https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript Image object to load the image and then append it to the dom. For example:

```
var imgObj = new Image(); 
imgObj.src = "http://s27.postimg.org/ya4yhbmzn/image_Example1.jpg";

imgObj.onload = function() {
   $('#myDiv').attr('data-image-src', this.src); 
   //Here you can initiate your animation
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on my end this code, getting the same as by placing the image directly in the load function.